# Microsoft Flow - Can it send to email to people included in the Lists Email column for that specific entry?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I need to enter data in Sharepoint Lists, when the data is entered a email goes out (triggered by Microsoft Flow). However, there is a email column in the Sharepoint List. I need the email to send to that specific person. Can flow do this and if not, what other options exist?

Does anyone have some good resources to learn flow at a deeper level?

Thanks,

Mg

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, Flow can do this.**

You would just use your custom field in the "To" field, inside the "Send an email" action.

I've included a very basic Flow that will capture the information from a list item, and use a custom column (in this case, just titled "E-Mail") to send an email.  This is triggered when an item is created in SharePoint:

[image]

In terms of learning about Flow, I would recommend [Microsoft Flow Learning Resources](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-flow-learning-resources-materials/).

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try this. I appreciate the help