# Get email from username by Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I have created a Sharepoint List with a button that triggers Flow.

[image]

In this Flow I want to send an email to the person from the column "Zapůjčeno - zo...". The name in this column is the user name of the MS Sharepoint user.

How to solve this?
For this example, the username is "Frantisek Dolejsi / IAB" and the email is "frantisek.dolejsi@o****.com

Comment: What is stored in the column "Zapůjčeno - zo..."? email address of user? Is this person or group column or single line of text column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

1. Create a Microsoft flow with trigger set to **For a selected item**.
2. Add **Send Email** action to your flow.
3. Set **To** field of email action to your list item field which contains the email address of user. If email address is not directly stored in list then you can fetch it using some action in Office 365 User connector.
4. Run the flow from list view using column formatting (as you are already doing).

Only catch here is to get the email address of user and it depends on how you store it in your SharePoint list.

If you have stored it in Person or Group column then you can using dynamic content in flow where you will find email address of corresponding field.

Check below references for more information:

1. [Trigger MS Flow On SharePoint List Items Based On Column Formatting](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/trigger-ms-flow-on-sharepoint-list-items-based-on-column-formatting/)
2. [Extracting email address field from Person object](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Extracting-email-address-field-from-Person-object/td-p/370627)
3. [Microsoft Flow - Can it send to email to people included in the Lists Email column for that specific entry?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/microsoft-flow-can-it-send-to-email-to-people-included-in-the-lists-email-colu)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It works!