# Flow Sends Email to Specific Persons

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have a Flow that scans a List for four 'Titles'; and, where the 'DueDate' equals 30 days send an email.

Everthing works. For test purposes I manually entered my email addressed into the 'Send and email' "To" field.

For the test there were three Members that meet the condition of 'Title' and 'DueDate'. When the Flow runs I get one Expiration email per person.

There is a MemberList (contains Member and Member supervisor Name and Email Address) and a MemberCertQualList (this is the List the Flow is currently acting on).

How do I update the Flow to ONLY email the Member to whom the expiring document belongs and his/her supervisor?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a person field in the list indicating the owner of the document, then you can directly use the person field to send email like this:[Microsoft Flow - Can it send to email to people included in the Lists Email column for that specific entry?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/microsoft-flow-can-it-send-to-email-to-people-included-in-the-lists-email-colu)

And for supervisor, if that is not a property in user profile, only listed in the Member list, you will need to OData query filter through the Member list, find the corresponding supervisor of the member who owns the file and use the email address to send Email.

References which may be helpful:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsnav-2016/hh169248(v=nav.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/powerautomate-and-sharepoint-odata-filter-queries

You can provide the structure of your flow so we can provide more suggestions about it.